# Add Custom Field to Criteria in ATTopic

Tags: plone

How do I add a field, say 'Contributors' in Archetype types, to be listed in **Field name** drop down menu? For example, in a fresh new Plone site, I can manage criteria at `events/aggregator/criterion_edit_form`. I want 'Contributors' and custom fields to be added as criteria.
BTW, I ever look into `Products/ATContentTypes/tool/topic.py`, it seems that I have to addIndex and make it 'enabled=True'. But how? Or do I go into wrong direction?
/marr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go into Site Setup and go to the collections configuration(or just append /portal_atct/atct_manageTopicIndex onto the site url) and manage which which are allowed to be used in collections.

You'll have to click the "All fields" button to see everything available. The caveat is that the only fields available are those that are indexes in the portal_catalog. So for your case, you'll need to add a contributors index in the portal_catalog in order to have it available in the form here.